# Prevent duplicate login in express + mongoDB session store

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session

I am using session to implement login in express, and mongoDB as session store.

I want to remove the logged-in session first in case of duplicate login.

But I don't know how to implement it.

Are there any examples or tutorials related to that?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a boolean entity isConnected in your user collection while it's true he can't connect if the user disconnect the value goes to false so he can.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are storing users as 'user' in req.session.user, and your sessions are stored in the MongoDB 'sessions' collection, and you are checking if a session with the email 'user.email' already exists, and if yes, delete the existing sessions(s).

```
await mongoose.connection.collection('sessions').deleteMany({ 'session.user.email': user.email })
```

This might look totally obvious, but it took me a few days to figure out, the 'normal' mongoose logic does not seem to work when it comes to sessions. (You would expect something like Session.deleteMany with a schema etc.). Instead you have to spell out the whole thing to access the collection.